# mongo find limit each match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a mongo collection which looks something like this:

```
{
  title: String,
  category: String
}
```

I want to write a query that selects various categories, similar to this:

```
Collection.find({category: {$in: ['Books', 'Cars', 'People']});
```

But I want to only select a limited number of each category, for example 5 of each book, car, people. How do I write such a query? Can I do it one query or must I use multiple ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using mongodb [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). Take a look at this pipeline:

1. Filter all documents by categories(using [$match](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)).
2. Group data by categories and create array for items with the same category(using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$push](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)).
3. Get a subset of each array with a limited maximum length(using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)).

Try the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {category: {$in: ['Books', 'Cars', 'People']}}}, 
  {$group: {_id: "$category", titles: {$push: "$title"}}}, 
  {$project: {titles: {$slice: ["$titles", 5]}}}
])
```

Comment: This does what I wanted, but how about the performance? If this is the best way to do it, is it faster than simply using a find for each category? And from what I understand I need to push every field I want, which is a problem if I don't know what fields does the item have

Comment: Performance is quite low because you need to build a large array and then create  a subset from it. I don't know any better way in order to do it. If you want to push all your fields to array you can take advantage of [$$CURRENT](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/). {$push: "$$CURRENT"}